# Split string in JavaScript using RegExp ignoring the delimiter inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have various instances of strings that I need to split. Following are some examples and the desired output scenarios. The rules to split are also listed:

Example 1:

```
input: 'filename.ext|someattributes'
output array: 
  'filename.ext', 
  'someattributes'
```

Example 2:

```
input: qualifier1[filename.ext|someattributes]|qualifier2[another_filename.ext|some_other_attributes]
output array: 
  'qualifier1[filename.ext|someattributes]',
  'qualifier2[another_filename.ext|some_other_attributes]'
```

Example 3:

```
input: dummyqualifier|qualifier1[filename.ext|someattributes]
output array: 
  'dummyqualifier', 
  'qualifier1[filename.ext|someattributes]'
```

The rules are simple. Split the string using '|' as delimiter only when it does not appear inside square brackets. Note: The string may not have any square brackets. There are no spaces in the input strings.

I am looking for a solution in JavaScript as this is for a node.js module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work for the cases you've outlined:

```
/\|(?!(?:\w+\|?)+])/
```

Here's an example of it running: http://jsfiddle.net/UFq3h/1/ (you will need to have the console opened to see the results).

Crude explanation: any <kbd>|</kbd> character *not* followed by (word characters or <kbd>|</kbd> followed by <kbd>]</kbd>). If you need a more precise explanation post a comment and I'll try to make it clearer.

Edit: Thanks to Lolo for the improved version, which handles the last example in the use case.

Comment: Thanks draevor. This works great. I think I understand how it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of regex right now, but you can do this:

```
function doSplit(input) {
    var tmp = input.split('|');

    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        result[j] = (result[j] ? result[j] + '|' : '') + tmp[i];
        if (result[j].indexOf('[') == -1 || result[j].indexOf(']') != -1) {
            j++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var i = 'qualifier1[filename.ext|someattributes]|qualifier2[another_filename.ext|some_other_attributes]';
var o = doSplit(i);
```

Comment: Thanks Lolo, appreciate your quick response.