# Split a string with comma separator but not when enclosed with [ ]

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a scenario where I'm reading a CSV file line by line. A common example of a line is

```
"name,description,str,"['A', 'B', 'C']","
```

I need to split the line into an array with comma separator but not when it exists inside '[]'.

Expected output in array:

```
name  
description  
str  
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Note: The last value in the provided input line is blank. That is why there is , and no text following that

I tried following the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471406/split-string-in-javascript-using-regexp-ignoring-the-delimiter-inside-brackets) but it didn't work for me

Comment: `common example of a line is "name,description,str,"['A', 'B', 'C']"," ` - meaning there's another format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split by commas but not within brackets using regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516862/split-by-commas-but-not-within-brackets-using-regexp)

Comment: use papaparse :p

Comment: What about the " before and after the [ and ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string in JavaScript using RegExp ignoring the delimiter inside brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471406/split-string-in-javascript-using-regexp-ignoring-the-delimiter-inside-brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in your case.

```js
var str = "name,description,str,['A', 'B', 'C'],";

var matches = str.match(/\[.*\]/g);

var arr = str.replace(/\[.*\]/g,'SomeRandomText').split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  arr[arr.indexOf('SomeRandomText')] = matches.shift();
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?[a-zA-Z(\[.*?\]")],
```

**How it works**

Within square bracket I am looking for the last acceptable characters before comma. Acceptable characters are English word characters (a-zA-Z) and characters inside square brackets. Character inside square brackets are grouped by parentheses so that they considered as one character and hence not splitted by the comma inside it